# Cannot get the size of a file without adding its extension( using JFileDialog)

Tags: java

This is what I have so far. When I type in the name of a file withouts its extension in JFileDialog i find the file but i cant get the size....with the extension I get the size...but I want to get it without its extension

```
public class DirScanner {

    public static void main(String[] argv) throws IOException {

        FileDialog fd = new FileDialog(new Frame());
        fd.setVisible(true);//make the jfilechooer visible
        if (fd.getFile() != null) {

            File f = new File(fd.getDirectory(), fd.getFile());//svae directory path and name of file
            String p = null;
            File fi = new File(fd.getDirectory());//store directory

            String[] d = fi.list();//store all file in directory
            for (int i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
                if (d[i] != null) {

                    //checks if wat the user type in the Jfieldoalog matches wat is in teh directory
                    if (d[i].matches(fd.getFile()) || d[i].startsWith(fd.getFile())) {

                        //gets the extension of teh file
                        p = d[i];
                        int dot = p.lastIndexOf(".");
                        String word = p.substring(0, dot);
                        String w = p.toUpperCase().substring(dot + 1);


                        System.out.println("\nFile Found\n");//output that file is found

                        //Display name of file with and without extension
                        System.out.println("Name of File: " + d[i]+  "\n"+  "File Name Without Extension: " + word + "\n" + "File type: " + w);
                    }
                }
            }
            //output size of fiel
            System.out.printf("size: " + f.length());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code and question don't make much sense. You're scanning the directory yourself to find the file, yet when you find it you don't get the length from that File, you get it from the File returned by the JileChooser.

Comment: I know something is wrong right there but I dont know how to fix it can u help?

Comment: I am new here so i really do not know how to view what have been edited...and suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. You are obtaining the file size in the last statement.

Comment: yes I am orien..and that is only possible if i enter the name of the file with its extension. But what I want is to enter the file name without its extension and still get the size of that file.

Comment: @EJP..anyone.. What suggestions do you guys have. I really need all the help I can get. Thanks in advance... If am not here just email me: tashauna_simon@yahoo.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try constructing a new File instance during your scan:

```
File file = new File(fd.getDirectory(), p);
System.out.println("size: " + file.length());
```

Comment: Thanks guys.. @orien it sure did work! whew! do u know anything about reading a file header to get the file type(extension) in java?

Answer (score 0):

Try to understand what a [`File` is in Java](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) and what is you are getting from the method `.list()`.

When you print "File found" you have actually just found the full name of a file that matches whatever you typed in the FileDialog. You need to [use that name to find the file size](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.io/getlength.html).